# Is it possible to store data directly inside an inode on a Unix / Linux filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, ufs

According to this [Red Hat bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1024095) (which I am trying to reproduce) it looks like the Netapp filer is able to store data directly in the inode, in case of very small files.

Considering I had a FS with large inodes, would it be possible to store data in such a way on a Unix / Linux file system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ext4` since kernel 3.8 supports this: it can store (very) small files within the inode, as described in the [filesystem layout documentation](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inline_Data).

Other filesystems support this on Linux too, or variants of the idea; for example [Btrfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs#Extents) stores small files in the parent extent.

Comment: Thanks. I will now have to find out out to create such files, though it will probably be the matter of a different question.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197633/how-to-use-the-new-ext4-inline-data-feature-storing-data-directly-in-the-inode?rq=1