# NFS mount reporting files below 65 bytes as using zero blocks

Tags: centos, nfs

I've encountered a puzzling issue with small files on an NFS4 mount.  Under 65 bytes they show as using zero data in certain scenarios.  This produces apprently empty looking files in (for example) `du` output.

```
# du -csh foo*
4.0K    foo               # 65 bytes
0       foo2              # 64 bytes
0       foo3              # 0 bytes
4.0K    total
```

The behaviour doesn't seem to belong to `du`, as `stat` shows something similar (as does `ls -ls`).

```
# stat foo* | grep -E "File|Size"
  File: ‘foo’
  Size: 65          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 65536  regular file
  File: ‘foo2’
  Size: 64          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 65536  regular file
  File: ‘foo3’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 65536  regular empty file
```

Using the following nfs package

```
nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.68.el7.2.x86_64
```

Mounted thus:

```
1.2.3.18:/test on /home/user/mnt type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=1.2.3.116,local_lock=none,addr=1.2.3.18)
```

It's not causing a problem as such, but the behaviour was unexpected.

Comment: What type of file system does the underlying exported file system use?

Comment: That information is not exposed to me unfortunately. Is the behaviour explainable by peculiarities of a particular file system?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show the full output of `stat foo2`?

Comment: Yes, the behaviour can be explained by [inline data storage](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/197633/86440) which is supported on a few file systems (such as Ext4). I’m not sure whether NFS actually exposes that however.

Comment: I wonder if NFS actually needs to do anything in particular to expose that, I'd assume it just passes on what the underlying filesystem does.